# GDAL/OGR ogrinfo for shapefiles in python

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, ogr, metadata

This might be a dumb question, but I wasn't able to find the answer anywhere.

Reading the metadata of a raster file in Python using GDAL is as easy as:

```
result = str(gdal.Info(raster.tif))
print result
```

In this case I want to do the same for a shapefile. I know I can use `ogrinfo -ro -so -al foo.shp` in the shell, but I have not found a way to do the same only in Python within a single line.

I'm looking for something like:

```
result = str(ogr.Info(shapefile.shp))
print result
```

Am I missing something obvious or is there really no function like this?

Comment: try something from https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-shapefile-feature-count

Comment: Already did that, but those only return specific information like feature count, extent, layer definition and so on. Of course I could get everything I'm looking for with multiple calls and afterwards append everything to a string, but that's why I'm looking for a function like `ogr.Info(shapefile.shp)`

Comment: Then it doesn't exist. Nothing shows up with `dir(ogr)` and I can't see anything in the docs. If you can hack a nice module from the cookbook recipes then it might be a nice thing to publish. You'd probably get some help... Start a project on gitlab today!

Comment: Well, then at least I have the peace of mind that I'm not blind. Was thinking the whole time that I was missing something quite basic. I currently don't have time at all to start a project, but will keep it in mind for future endeavours!

Comment: Use [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) or [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/), based on ogr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more convoluted way to call anything gdal-related, using the subprocess module :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

args = ['ogrinfo', '-ro', '-so', '-al', 'bacon.shp']
process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

stdout = process.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()
print(stdout)
```

This acts as a virtual shell of sorts, and prints out whatever the shell returns. Here's some [documentation about subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess). It might be a bit heavy for what you want to do, but I've found it very useful for some tasks I had to do which weren't do-able using the GDAL module.

(NB. The decode/strip part is there just so that  the output looks nicer.)

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! Not the one-liner that I was looking for, but definetly more compact (and maybe useful in the future!) than calling every single attribute and slapping it together in a string.