# How to use ogrinfo in a Python script

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I've been using OGR/GDAL in its command window to obtain information regarding a vector file with this command

```
ogrinfo -so -al d:/vector_file.shp
```

I'm now trying to do the equivalent of this feature in a Python script but I'm unsure how to do it?

I tried looking in this documentation  https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-shapefile-feature-count

but couldn't find any examples with ogrinfo or how to explicitly state the arguments

I've also seen the answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280900/2581, but would rather not use the `subprocess` module and instead the `osgeo`

Comment: Duplicate of [GDAL/OGR ogrinfo for shapefiles in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280900/2581) ?

Comment: @gene I had seen this answer, but thought there might be a way to use ```from osgeo``` rather than ```subprocess```. Is this not the case?

Comment: If you want to use the external binary, then `subprocess` is the route. If you want to do the *equivalent* in Python, then you need to rewrite the Question to ask that.

Comment: @Vince sorry, I've modified the question now

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429788/ogrinfo-specify-what-information-you-want-returned/429793. The whole ogrinfo is also written as a python script in the code samples https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/ogrinfo.py.

Comment: @user30184 I can't understand that code. Is there not an easier way to execute similar results?

Comment: It implements almost all the same features than the ogr2ogr executable including how to handle the options and error cases. Is there some special piece of information about vector layers that you are interested in?

Comment: @user30184 I'm just unsure how to execute the script properly

Comment: As usual https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/#using-the-python-command `python ogrinfo.py` followed by the arguments.

Comment: @dabba293 facing the same question - have you fonud a way to use osgeo library to accomplish this?